# How can someone using public wifi be deanonymized?

Tags: wifi, anonymity, deanonymization

Say someone wants to send a document overseas while living in a hostile country. He uses tor over public wifi. What are some ways he can be tracked if he uses a burner laptop and public wifi? Few ways I can think of:

1. CCTV cameras or people looking over his shoulder
2. Opsec failures like logging into an account linked to him
3. Something about the document can link to him (like metadata and stylometry)
4. Wifi Positioning

To defeat (1), can he be still be tracked if he writes a script to send the document, but keep his laptop in a closed bag?

Can he defeat (4) by sitting in a crowded place or moving around in a crowd while the script executes?